# Nginx + Pyodbc (UnixODBC) + Gunicorn + Django : [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, gunicorn, unixodbc

I am getting:

```
[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)"
```

error while creating connection using `PyODBC`. This works fine when I use it via Django Development server. But on using it via. `Gunicorn` and `Nginx`, it fails.

I faced this issue in the past (while configuring the Development server) when:

1. Some of the libraries needed by UnixODBC were missing. Since, it is working with Django development server, this couldn't be the issue
2. When environment variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` do not had the path to my driver.

Most likely I think 2nd is the cause. I tried setting up the environment variables in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment` but no luck. Does anyone have idea regarding what might be wrong here?

It has nothing to do with `Gunicorn` as directly running the gunicorn server using:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 my_project.wsgi:application
```

works fine. **Issue is while communication with Nginx via wsgi.**

---

All the required environment methods are setted up correctly:

```
mquadri@MY_HOST:/tmp/webadmin$ env
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nz/lib64
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/nz/bin64
NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH=/home/mquadri/CONFIG
HOME=/home/mquadri
ODBCINI=/home/mquadri/CONFIG/odbc.ini
NETEZZA=/usr/local/nz
```

All the related dependencies are already installed. Below is the ouput of  `ldd` in case someone might find it useful:

```
mquadri@MY_HOST:/tmp/webadmin$ ldd /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff96dfa000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f286f0f1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f286edeb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f286ebcc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f286e9c8000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f286e7e8000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f286e6da000)
    libcom_err.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libcom_err.so.3 (0x00007f286e5d7000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f286e494000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f286f806000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f286e278000)
```

---

If I set these environment variables explicitly in `settings.py` development server runs fine, but `nginx` gives `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: What are the permissions for `/usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so`?

Comment: I thought it might be permission related issue, so I changed it to 777, along with the complete path to it from `nz`

Comment: It looks to me that any of the environment variable that I am setting explicitly for ODBC is been overridden by any of the Nginx variable.